# Tensorflow 1.3 and CUDA 8.1

Tags: tensorflow

I am running Tensorflow 1.3 with CUDA 8.0 atop of Ubuntu 16.04 successfully. The setup has been done according the official installation instructions.

1) I am wondering if Tensorflow is compatible with CUDA 9 as well. Is this supported? If so, is there a significant performance gain?

2) If only CUDA 8 is supported: is cuDNN 7.0.3 supported?

Answer (score -1):

Version compatibility Tensorflow can be viewed at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)